# Dependable dropdown on dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Can someone help me and give me a clue about this

im trying to add dependable dropdown whenever i click add more but in my case the first field only works whenever i click add more the category tab works but it cannot fetch the equipment its far from the way i want to , i want to work it like if i click category the equipments will show and if i click add more it does the same function

[image]
[image]
here is my code:

```
$bquery = $db->query("SELECT * FROM category ");
            $browCount = $bquery->num_rows;

                 <td><select class="form-control" id="category" name="category[]">
                 <option value="">---Select Category---</option>
                  <?php 
                if($browCount > 0){ 
            while($row = $bquery->fetch_assoc()){ 
                echo '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                     }
                  }else{ echo  '<option value="">Category not available</option>'; }
                 ?></select></td>
                <td><select class="form-control" id="equipments" name="equipments[]">  <option value="">---Select
            Equipment---</option></select></td>
```

My Script

```
            <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              var i=1;

              $('#add').click(function(){
                i++;
                $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select 
          class="form-control" id="category" name="category"><option
        value="">---Select Category---</option><?php 
                foreach ($Result as $col) {  ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $col["cat_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $col["cat_name"]; ?></option> <?php }  ?>
     </select></td><td><select class="form-control" id="equipments" name="equipment "><option value="">---Select
        Equipment---</option></select></td>> <td><button type="button"
        name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger
        btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
             });

              $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
                var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
                $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
              });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain more what your expecting ? What's the Add More button functionality ?

Comment: i have the picture link attach above ... 

the add more button adds another select option field so that every time i click the button it another field added

...The problem is on the first select option field the code works fine it show the category and equipment 
https://i.imgur.com/W3ij1xF.png
but then i click the button the category code only works and cannot fetch the equipment on 2nd field
https://i.imgur.com/kbSdjhI.png

Comment: I don't see any code which fetch equipment data.since you wanted to add the control dynamically in java script your approach should be once you have added the control you have to send ajax post to get the equipment information from DB and append the response to the equipment select control.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

          $('#category').on('change',function(){
        var catID = $(this).val();
        if(catID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'data.php',
                data:'cat_id='+catID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#equipments').html(html);
                   
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#equipments').html('<option value="">Select Equipment First</option>');
          
        }
    });
});
</script>

Comment: i have that one hmm im quite confused sir

Comment: what is output of `console.log(catID)`?

Answer (score 0):

The id attribute of the category and equipment must be unique.

> ID's are unique Each element can have only one ID Each page can have
>   only one element with that ID

you can chage your code some think like below.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
            i++;
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><select 
      class="form-control"   onchange="categorychage(this,'+i+')" name="category"><option
    value="">---Select Category---</option><?php 
            foreach ($Result as $col) {  ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $col["cat_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $col["cat_name"]; ?></option> <?php }  ?>
 </select></td><td><select class="form-control" id="equipments'+i+'" name="equipment "><option value="">---Select
    Equipment---</option></select></td>> <td><button type="button"
    name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger
    btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
         });

   $("row"+i).find("[name=category]").trigger("change");

          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
          });
        });
```

Change event action will be separate function

```
function categorychage(cat,equipmentsid)
        {
            var catID = $(cat).val();
          if (catID) {
           $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'data.php',
            data: 'cat_id=' + catID,
            success: function(html) {
             $('#equipments').html(html);
            }
           });
          } else {
           $('#equipments'+equipmentsid).html('<option value="">Select Equipment First</option>');
          }
        }
```

if you look at the code i have removed the category id attribute and changed the equipment id attribute for each one by appending the "i" variable.

hope this helps

you need to change this code as well

```
<td><select class="form-control" id="category"  onchange="categorychage(this,0)" name="category[]">
             <option value="">---Select Category---</option>
              <?php 
            if($browCount > 0){ 
        while($row = $bquery->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
                 }
              }else{ echo  '<option value="">Category not available</option>'; }
             ?></select></td>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="equipments0" name="equipments[]">  <option value="">---Select
        Equipment---</option></select></td>
```

Comment: i doesnt work but you give me an idea sir so i can change the name of element by adding increment value to change its element name something like that?...i might try  some of my ideas

Comment: Changing the category and equipment id value should solve your problem.
 what was the error ?

Comment: it doesnt have an error but still it cannot get the values of equipment on the 2nd field after clicking the add more button

Comment: can you try to change the second second filter category and see

Comment: when i changed it , it doesnt fetch the equipment anymore ...ill try to re check it

Comment: when i check it i saw this one 
Uncaught ReferenceError: categorychage is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange 

categorychage(this,2)

Comment: great thanks sir kudoz you gave me a hint and show me the code its all thanks to you now i can proceed